# Install sass version of twitter bootstrap with bower

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to install twitter bootstrap-sass with compass on windows. I'm installed any require things and now I have folder with this structure after running 
"compass create my-new-project -r bootstrap-sass --using bootstrap" command in cmd :

```
site
 |_ .sass-cache folder
 |_ javascripts 
 | |_ bootstrap folder 
 | |_ bootstrap.js 
 | |_ bootstrap-sprockets.js 
 |_ sass 
 | |_ bootstrap-variables.scss 
 | |_ styles.scss 
 |_ stylesheets 
 | |_ fonts 
 | |_ styles
 |_ config.rb
```

so how can I use twitter bootstrap now ?

NOTE: I think my sass files is not completely import to this folder (just two files !!!)

Comment: It doesn't look like you're currently using bower. Do you have it configured? what's the output of `bower -v`?

Answer (score 15):

To initialize a bower project after you've installed bower you can do

```
bower init
```

This will walk you through an interactive prompt to setup your bower.json file.

Once bower is setup, you can do:

```
bower install bootstrap-sass-official --save
```

This will download and install the sass version of Bootstrap to `./bower_components`

Once that is complete, you can require bootstrap in `styles.scss` like so:

```
//= require ../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.scss
```

However, because you're using compass, you might just want to use the bootstrap-sass gem by following the instructions here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#b-compass-without-rails

Comment: I do that instructions step by step and now, I have folder with same instruction, but I found same instruction on github link that you wrote. so It seems my folder and files instruction is true. But now how can I using bootstrap ? NOTE: I can not understand why I have just two sass files :(

Comment: Sorry to revive the dead here, I followed your instructions, but all of bootstraps scss files have underscores... making them throw an error on preprocessing. Is there a reason they are all prefixed with an underscore?

Comment: Nvm... apparently I had a type.

Comment: ++ I was originally using `bootstrap-sass` as the package and that's gone now! `bootstrap-sass-official` was the fix for me :D